# Does Redis Replication help in load balancing?

Tags: redis

We keep continuously writing and updating events into redis and so when we ever we want to read data(which is a lot of data , upwards of for 500000 key value pairs), redis has performance issues. So, we decided to get the data via multiple threads. But because of single instance redis , the performance issues persisted .Will replication help us? As in, by making master and slave redis's , will our reads of the events be distributed to the slaves . We are thinking of making the master write only.
Any other suggestion for performance improvements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(one of) Replication's declared purposes is to help in scaling reads, so yes to the topic.

Note that after you've set up the slave, you'll need to specify its address for your reader threads and processes. Make sure that you start with read-slaves if you don't have a clear separation between writers and readers.

If a single slave isn't enough, you can actually add more slaves. If you add them directly to the master, you'll get fresher reads but there'll eventually be a performance impact on the master. Alternatively, replication chaining is a great solution for most use cases, i.e. 1 master -> 1 slave -> n slaves.

There are probably other ways to scale Redis for your use case (e.g. clustering), but that really depends on what you're trying/wanting to do :)